# Control of sd-card pins in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, sd-card, linux-device-driver

Is it possible to control SD card reader register pins from Linux via C/C++ ? I have seen people doing it for pcmcia. But never with sd.

Comment: you need to write a driver to access the hardware, and then you can do it in any way you want. If the existing driver you have supports this functionality - then use it. If not - bummer.

Comment: Is your SD reader on USB or on the mobo?

Comment: Its an laptop integrated reader, I have written only simple pcmcia driver so far, is this more complex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use lspci to list the devices on your motherboard.  From that you can find the hardware driver.  If it doesn't already have the capability, you can add ioctl calls to the driver to read and write registers.

Comment: How do i know which of those is my driver, it doesnt have a good description. Of course, i see the difference between eg. gpu and ethernet controller.
Here s the output  [link](http://pastebin.com/z4quirML)